# Azure devops roll back to a previous commit for Azure Data Factory

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I realized I made 10 bad commit in  particular branch (main) for Azure data factory code repository. How do I eliminate all 10 latest bad commits and revert to commit when thing were fine using Azure Devops. I do not have git installed on my work machine, so I could perform git reset
[image]

Comment: "I do not have git installed on my work machine, so I could perform git reset". Did you mean to say "so I *cannot* perform git reset"? It sounds like `reset` may be what you want to do here though. In this case, are you asking if there's way to do a hard reset in Azure DevOps without having a local copy?

Comment: It looks like `main` is shared. So you'll need to decide if you can easily "reset" the branch without messing others up. If not you'll need to "revert" those 10 commits in a single commit which undoes the previous 10. This can easily be done from a local repo, and possibly can be done in AzDO somehow as well. Are you not able to have a local copy of the repo to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1 ：Revert the Commits Using Azure DevOps Web Interface:

- Open the commits page and click on the last bad commit.
  [image]
- Choose the Revert option.
  [image]
- A temp branch will be created with the reverted changes, and then you will be prompted to create a pull request to the target branch.
- After the pull request is completed, the last bad commit is reverted.
  [image]
- You need to do the above steps for all the ten bad commits. At last, it looks like this in the history: [image]

#### Solution 2: Using Git Commands in Azure DevOps pipeline (since you mentioned you don’t have Git installed)

**Please make sure you have a backup of the code or created a backup branch in case any accident lost code during the process.**

- Open the commits page, click on the last good commit and copy the commit ID
  [image]
- We will run the git command with the [build service account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities)    `Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})`  or `{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})`  in the pipeline. You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#how-do-i-determine-the-job-authorization-scope-of-my-yaml-pipeline) to determine the build service account of your YAML pipeline.
  [image]
  Give the account permission: Contribute and force push.
  [image]
- Create a pipeline based on the repo with the following yaml.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
 - checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

 - script: |
    git config --global user.email "myemail@email.com"
    git config --global user.name "me"
    git remote update
    git fetch
    git checkout main
    git reset --hard <your good commit ID here> #revert back to the good commit
    git push --force
```

- After the pipeline run successfully, the history of the main branch is like this: [image]
- Delete the pipeline and change back the permission of the service account to avoid the pipeline accidently runs by other users.