# How to Revert once bug branch from a merged Main branch

Tags: c#, git, azure-devops

I was trying remove the branch which already merged to the main branch. I am getting merge conflicts.  I am using azure-repose save the code. The below image is the error i am getting, How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: You'll need to do what the error message says- which is revert the merge locally. You'll need to learn how to revert a merge commit, followed by how to resolve conflicts.

Answer (score -1):

Git merge conflicts occur when two or more branches have made conflicting changes to the same part of a file.  In your case, some files are changed after the pull request is merged.

If you don't want to keep the changes after the merge, you can revert the latest commit one by one and there will no conflicts anymore. You can refer the steps in [my another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78079316/16162444).

If you want to keep the changes after the pull request, you need revert the merge locally. You can refer [this question: How do I revert a merge commit that has already been pushed to remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099833/how-do-i-revert-a-merge-commit-that-has-already-been-pushed-to-remote).